# How to improve rows estimating

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, enterprise-edition

I have a query from thirdparty app to our tables.
The problem is that execute takes up to 10 minutes.
Here is the plan of long execution
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=r1_tLDGHh
As I see, the main problem is that sql estimate to read 15 rows from Shard2.dbo.Aggregation, but actual rows is around 250k.
When i delete join on #CampaignIds (which have 15 rows), query executes in 15-20 seconds.
Here is the plan for it
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=rkR9IDGHn
What I tried to do:

- updated statistics on Aggregation
- created statistics on Aggregation.CampaignId
- created fitered statistics on Aggrecation.CampaignId + AdvertisingAppId by current year
  But estimates still on the same level or was less then before.
  What else I can try (for now, i can't rewrite the query)?

Comment: What version and edition of SQL Server (I see Adaptive Joins so must be recent)? What are the table definitions and index definitions of those tables? Please add these details to your Post. Unfortunately I think you're going to find that the root issue is the query itself and will require a rewrite.

Comment: 2019 Enterprise

Comment: And the other information I asked about? (Please add to your Post.)